# How to make a label with the background color as a color chosen by the user?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

So, here is my code. Essentially, what I want to do is to make a label with the background color the same as the color chosen in the color dialog, so that the person can see the color and the color hexadecimal code. Please help.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry("600x300+500+500")
mGui.title("Hexadecimal Color Chooser")

def getColor():
    mycolor = colorchooser.askcolor()
    label = Label(mGui, bg = mycolor).pack()
    mycolor = str(mycolor)
    start = mycolor.index("#")
    stop = mycolor.index("')")
    mycolor = mycolor[start:stop]
    label = Label(mGui, text = "The hexadecimal color code is: " + mycolor).pack()

button = Button(mGui, text = "Choose a color", command = getColor).place(x=0, y=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues here:

1. Importing `sys` if you are not going to use it does nothing.
2. The `place`, `pack`, and `grid` methods of Tkinter widgets always return `None`.  Hence, any calls to them should always be placed on their own line.
3. `tkinter.colorchooser.askcolor` returns a two-item tuple like this:

   ```
   ((128.5, 64.25, 64.25), '#804040')
   ```

   Futhermore, the last item in this tuple is the hex code of the chosen color.

Below is a fixed version of the script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry("600x300+500+500")
mGui.title("Hexadecimal Color Chooser")

def getColor():
    color_choice = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]  # get the hex code
    color = Label(mGui, bg=color_choice)
    color.pack()
    hexcode = Label(mGui, text="The hexadecimal color code is: "+color_choice)
    hexcode.pack()

button = Button(mGui, text="Choose a color", command=getColor)
button.place(x=0, y=0)

mGui.mainloop()
```